# How to make a delegatecall to external ERC20 token's approve function?

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, delegatecall, erc-20-approve

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
function testCall(uint amount) public virtual returns (bool) {
address tta = address(0xE7B6....);    
    
(bool success, bytes memory result) = tta.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("approve(address, uint256)", address(this), amount));
return success;
}
```

The token looks like [this](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol) (has the approve function)

However, whenever the function is executed, it reverts with an [error](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xe4e3a56f6dc20f9c58c96106d857860a23a4e1af6d2dacd9d2b0d60c4a95d385).

What am I doing wrong?

What I need to accomplish is to let the user approve the contract to make a `transferFrom` by executing the contract's `testCall()` function first.

Comment: Get rid of the space character in `"approve(address, uint256)"`.

Comment: As you can learn from [the official documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/abi-spec.html?highlight=selector#function-selector): "Parameter types are split by a single comma - no spaces are used".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a space in your function which is producing a different method signature.

```
> provider.eth.abi.encodeFunctionSignature('approve(address, uint256)')
0x8b069f2a

provider.eth.abi.encodeFunctionSignature('approve(address,uint256)')
0x095ea7b3
```

If you remove the space, it should work!

Comment: Edit: yes, it works!  (sorry it took so long to approve the answer)